# patindex t-sql special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to check if any of this `!@#$%^&*()_-+` special characters exist in a string ?

i tried

```
SELECT PATINDEX('!@#$%^&*()_-+', 'test-');  
SELECT PATINDEX('[!@#$%^&*()_-+]', 'test-');  
SELECT PATINDEX('%[!@#$%^&*()_-+]%', 'test-');
```

but all returns 0, it should return 5, any help ?

Comment: Those aren't special characters. Why do you want to check for their existence in SQL? Are you trying to "clean" user input or passwords? That would be the wrong way to do it.

Comment: In any case you *can* use eg `LIKE` or `PATINDEX` to check for multiple characters by [putting them inside square brackets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/wildcard-character-s-to-match-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), escaped when necessary. Performance though will be **very bad**. The server wouldn't be able to use any indexes to check for characters in the middle of a string. What are you trying to do? There are probably better, faster ways to do it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i use to check if input variable has any of them, and if anyone is found to return 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-` is a special character in the `LIKE` or `PATINDEX()` pattern.  If it is anywhere other than the first position, it is a range of characters -- such as all digits being represented by `[0-9]`.

You can do what you want by moving the condition:

```
PATINDEX('%[-!@#$%^&*()_+]%', 'test-'),
```

Unfortunately, `PATINDEX()` patterns don't support an escape character.  You can also express this logic as a `LIKE` and `CASE`:

```
(CASE WHEN 'test-' LIKE '%[-!@#$%^&*()_+]%' ESCAPE '$' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Or using a "not" pattern:

```
(CASE WHEN 'test-' NOT LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z]%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use negation:

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%[^a-Z]%', 'test-');
```

This will find a character NOT in the range a-Z.

Comment: This will also exclude numbers. Although, it's far safer than trying to exclude "special" characters

Comment: @HoneyBadger thank you for the answer however i need to handle only !@#$%^&*()_-+ because i replace other later

Comment: @MasterYi so if I enter `αυτό εδώ` you'd allow it? If you want to use such matching for input cleaning it will fail far too easily

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes i convert some of this characters, but if name have  character - the conversion is getting messed up ( e.g αυτό is convertd  to AJto  instead of Auto )

Comment: @MasterYi why do such an arbitrary conversion then? There's absolutely nothing wrong with Unicode in SQL Server - in fact, it supported Unicode since day 1. SO itself uses SQL Server which is why I knew I could type a Greek string and have it appear in the page

Comment: @MasterYi in fact, I could type Greek, Arabic and Chinese all in the same comment and be certain it would appear correctly. No conversions are necessary. No special coding or encoding either - ASP.NET uses Unicode for *all* text*. As long as you write a correct SQL statement you can store and retrieve Unicode from/to nvarchar fields just fine

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos client demands :) and I don't have choice to change

Comment: @MasterYi client demands what? To mangle input and convert it to an unrecognizable form? That can't be used to satisfy *any* business process? I doubt it. If the customer said "I want to store all text safely" the answer would be "you already can". Just use `nchar` or `nvarchar` fields and parameterized queries

Comment: @MasterYi it's far more likely someone, somewhere tried to store Unicode in ASCII fields, or used string concatenation to pass values. That's a bug. You can't cover this up with cleaning or converting to arbitrary ASCII characters. Fixing the bug will be a lot easier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174639/discussion-between-master-yi-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%[-+!_@()*^#$%&]%', 'test-');
```

this solves my issue returns 5 the positon of -.

Apperently order matters.

Comment: The problem is, `-` appearing anywhere other than as the first character within square brackets makes it a character range specifier for the characters before and after it. I thought that was explicitly called out in the documentation, but other than it being used in an example (to point out that `[a-cdf]` matches a, b, c, d or f, but `[-acdf]` matches a, c, d, f or `-`), it's not highlighted that I can see.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever there is no mention here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017, thanks for explanation

Comment: Yeah, like I said, not called out well. The example I was looking at was under [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-wildcard-characters-as-literals)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @myString VARCHAR(100) ='test-'
IF (@myString LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%')
    PRINT 'Contains "special" characters'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Does not contain "special" characters'
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select patindex('%[' + char(45) + ']%', 'test-');
```

But symbol '-' not working in range values, replace this symbol on another symbol.

Next example find only writable symbols in `@string`:

```sql
declare @string varchar(max) = char(8) + char(9) + char(10) + char(11) + char(12) + char(13) + '-test string-';
select patindex(%[' + char(33) + '-' + char(255) + ']%', replace(@string, '-', '#'))
```